# fast system calls in R

Tags: python, r, parallel-processing

I have a nest for loop inside which I run a python script using the system call option in R, I found that all the execution time of my code is spent just on the system call in order to run the python script, so I was wondering if there is any tricks that I can use to save this great loss of time spent on repeatedly using the system call especially cause the python script in itself only take 1 second per each call, the problem is that I can't run the .py script independently cause I's using some parameters generated by other parts in R.  here is a snapshot of my code and any suggestion is highly appreciated:

```
 for(x in 1:10000){
    .......
    for (y in 1:10000){
    .....
    x=system("python calc.py -c1 -c2",intern = TRUE)
    }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not at all related to R. What takes time is to launch the python script. What you should do ? Either modify the python script to take more input at a time, or implement it in R

Comment: Even if each call would only take 1 sec, 1e8 calls would take about 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what calc.py does. It does not seem to take any arguments that depend on x and y, so this should work (unless you have left out critical knowledge):

```
x=system("python calc.py -c1 -c2",intern = TRUE)
for(x in 1:10000){
  .......
  for (y in 1:10000){
    .....
  }
}
```

If the calculation depends on x and y but that each calculation do not depend on each other (i.e. you do not need the result from the previous calculation to do the next) then you ought to be able to do something like:

```
for(x in 1:10000){
  .......
  for (y in 1:10000){
    .....
    push(mystack, c(x, y));
  }
}
save_arg_file("argfile",mystack)
z <- system("cat argfile | parallel calc.py -c1 -c2", intern = TRUE)
```

This way you can parallelize the calculations thus run faster than the 3 years.